# How to populate DNS suffixes on Nmap hostname scans in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, dns, nmap

I need a Kali box on my network to be able to properly retrieve DNS suffixes from the DNS servers when using Nmap scans.

When I run Nmap hostname scans from my own machine, I can watch the traffic in Wireshark and see that Nmap is trying each DNS suffix listed in CMD `ipconfig /all` - this is the expected behavior.

When I run the same scans against the same hostnames using a Kali box on my network, I see Nmap query the DNS server for the hostname, but it never tries the hostname with any of the DNS suffixes that should be provided by said DNS server.

The DNS server IP's are correct and auto-populating, and if I `dig dns.suffix` I get the expected results - so it seems at least the Kali machine itself is able to query them properly

It seems like Nmap isn't querying the DNS server for the suffixes, or the DNS server is refusing the query for some reason.

I've run Nmap with --system-dns pointed at the DNS servers and I get no results.
I've verified that resolv.conf has the proper DNS servers, and I've rebooted/restarted networkmanager and resolv services several times

Do I need to input all of my DNS suffixes somewhere for Nmap to automatically try them when scanning hostnames?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working temporary solution:

Add a 'dns-search' entry to /etc/network/interfaces with the domains of interest, like so:
`dns-search dns.suffix1 dns.suffix2 dns.suffix3`

I'm still not sure why the Kali isn't pulling this info from the dns servers, and if anyone can figure it out I'd appreciate it and flag it as the proper answer.

Another user explaining dns-search better than I can (from https://askubuntu.com/a/265815/1570220):

> dns-search determines which domain is appended for dns lookups.
>
> Normally you will specify here the same domain as returned by hostname  -f.
>
> For detailed information see the following quote from man resolv.conf:
>
> search Search list for host-name lookup.
> The  search  list  is  normally  determined from the local domain name; >by
> default, it contains only the local domain name.  This may be changed by listing
> the desired domain search path following the search keyword with spaces or tabs
> separating  the  names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots (default
> is 1) in them will be attempted using each component of the search path in turn
> until a match is found.  For environments with multiple  subdomains  please read
> options ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and unnecessary traffic
> for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this process may be slow and will generate
> a lot of network traffic if the servers for the  listed  domains  are not local,
> and that queries will time out if no server is available for one of the domains.
>
> The search list is currently limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters.